# How to make HTTP request to WAMP server on Android emulator

Tags: java, android, mysql, wamp, okhttp

I was originally using a tutorial on android hive:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

It turns out that some of the code was deprecated for HTTP requests and I've already looked at the documentation for OkHttp. I am trying to test out some PHP files but I keep getting a "failure" and an exception for all the different IP addresses. My WAMP icon is green and I can reach localhost in browser but not on Android emulator. The PHP files are working properly. I've already used 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.1XX, 10.0.0.2, and localhost but no IP address is working when making the request. I've even turned off my firewall and anti-virus but it doesn't make a difference. I just keep getting a logcat that says failure over and over again. I tested out movie DB API earlier and it was working fine, so this has to do with the URL. How can I get connect to WAMP via android emulator?

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplication(),
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        try {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("10.0.2.2:80/android_connect/create_product.php")
                    .build();
            Log.i("tag", "success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("tag", "failure");
            }
    }

}
```

The errors are sporadic. Different IP's give me a different error. Either way it keeps throwing an exception. This is also my first post, so I don't really know how to format errors. When I use 10.0.2.2, it's the following:

07-20 22:16:15.694 9958-9958/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-20 22:16:15.694 9958-9958/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-20 22:16:15.716 9958-9968/? E/art: Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
07-20 22:16:15.805 9962-9962/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-20 22:16:15.805 9962-9962/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-20 22:16:16.428 1971-2311/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae48e1e0
07-20 22:16:16.548 1178-1241/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property

Comment: Whats the error? Providing it is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually used the emulator to check what IP address would give me the WAMP homepage, it turns out that the IP4 address and 10.0.2.2 are working and I changed the port in http.conf file as well, so the port must be working now. The android hive tutorial I was using was outdated so the PHP files and JSON response might be the problem.

It turns out that I was missing "http://" in the link.

Answer thread:
[Retrofit-IllegalArgumentException: unexpected url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675010/retrofit-illegalargumentexception-unexpected-url)